# Email addresses & Abstract missing when using the elsarticle class

Tags: xetex, arabic, elsarticle, arabxetex

I am trying to format my paper using Latex with the class **elsarticle** for an Elsevier journal. I am using TeXnicCenter along with Miktex.

It's working perfectly when the content is all in English (compiled with **pdflatex**).
Working example:

```
\documentclass[3p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
%\usepackage{arabxetex}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

%\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Traditional Arabic}


\journal{Example Journal}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{A title for the paper}

% include affiliations in footnotes:
\author[mymainaddress]{Author1\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
\cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
\ead{info@example.com}

\author[mymainaddress]{Author2}
\ead{info2@example.com}
\address[mymainaddress]{Affiliation}

\begin{abstract}
  Your abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\begin{keyword}
   word1 \sep word2 \sep word3.
\end{keyword}
\end{frontmatter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, the thing is that my paper has some Arabic scripts. To make them appear and work properly, I use the commented packages in the previous code and compile it with **XeLatex**. This compiles with some warnings, but the resulted PDF is missing the whole **frontmatter** part!
[image]

And I get this compilation error message:

**! LaTeX Error: \begin{frontmatter} on input line 21 ended by \end{document}.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your .tex file with ShareLaTeX, to ensure that it is not a problem with the version of elsarticle you are using?